# Where is the getInputStream() function in java 1.8?

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to create a chat application between 2 computer. While i was writing the code in java, i have noticed that there is no getInputStream function in serverSocket object. How can i get the sockets inputStream.

Comment: You need to accept a connection first. That will return a Socket, which has a getInputStream(). Why don't you read the javadoc, or the Java socket tutorial? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Comment: Ahh okay thank you. Is docs.oracle is enough for socket programming.

Comment: Well, at least start there. It's enough to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...no, there wouldn't be, `ServerSocket`s don't have streamed input/output. A [`ServerSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) accepts connections, creating a [`Socket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) for each connection received (see [`accept`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept--)), which is where the streams for that connection are.